# Fisher's exact test analysis and analysing time period

Tags: r, spss

I would like to analysis two variables to test the correlation among to set of data. One of the variables is "string" and the other one is "date" (which is a period of time). As I understood the adequate test should be "Fisher's exact test" for my propose.

As there are lots of 0s in some categories, as a result it is not possible to run Chi-square test. I am thinking of running Fisher's exact test but do not know how because I am quite new in R.

The sample of the data:

```
  **Parking locations**           `Time sequence`
        Other locations             9:30-13:00
        Bicycle shed (Ground floor) 17:00-20:00
        Bicycle parking (East side) 6:00-9:30
        Bicycle shed (Ground floor) 13:00-17:00
        Bicycle shed (First floor)  9:30-13:00
        Bicycle shed (First floor)  13:00-17:00
        Bicycle shed (Ground floor) 13:00-17:00
        Bicycle shed (Ground floor) 13:00-17:00
        Supervised bicycle parking  6:00-9:30
        Bicycle shed (Ground floor) 6:00-9:30
```

My question is to know whether it is possible to run the analysis in `Spss` or I should use `R`.?
Moreover, what should be the data type for `Time sequence` column while it is period of time (9:30 to 13:00)?

Comment: Which hypothesis do you want to test?

Comment: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/fisher.test.html

Comment: @SvenHohenstein, I want to know if there is a relation between the preferred parking location and time of bicycle parking?

Comment: Maybe use `regex` to extract the starting time (assuming you want to analyse location vs. arrival time), or if you want the **length** of parking time, split the time strings so you can calculate the elapsed time, and then run statistical tests on  times grouped by location.  Use `plyr` or `aggregate` functions.

Comment: I see that there are multiples of each time sequence. Is that your original data? I assume that you want the four time intervals (6:00-9:30, 9:30-13:00, 13:00-17:00, 17:00-20:00) and not the length of the parking time. Right?

Comment: @A.Amidi It is a `dataframe` or a table or it is in Spss format? Do you want to distinguish between Bicycle and Supervised bicycle?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I'd make sure your data is in a comma-separated format (csv). This way, you could simply read in the data as shown into R using `read.csv`.

If you want to use them as categorical variables, you can simply use `R`:

```
fisher.test(parking_location, time_sequence)
```

I'll update the answer accordingly as more specific information becomes available; this works in the case that the strings (e.g. `Bicycle shed (First floor)` and  `Bicycle shed (Ground floor)`) are unique, and it considers the intervals also to be fixed.

Comment: But the `parking_location` is a string, and it seems not all of them are equal.

Comment: Yea, but like you pointed out, it depends if he wants to treat them as unique or not. If they are distinct, this approach is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

I typed your data into a [csv file.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b89ujbizu2mhu9f/bikes.csv) (Remark: Your data looks tab seperated because of the aligned second column, that would work as well)

Then you can do that in R:

```
data=read.csv("~/bikes.csv", header=T)
t<-table(data)
fisher.test(t)
```

The content of t and the result of the fisher test can be seen in [this screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sYGs.png)

and here is the copied output:

```
> t
                         Time.sequence
Parking.locations             13:00-17:00 17:00-20:00 6:00-9:30 9:30-13:00
  Bicycle parking (East side)           0           0         1          0
  Bicycle shed (First floor)            1           0         0          1
  Bicycle shed (Ground floor)           3           1         1          0
  Other locations                       0           0         0          1
  Supervised bicycle parking            0           0         1          0
> fisher.test(t)

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  t 
p-value = 0.419
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

That is a very basic example of the command

```
?fisher.test
```

you can see that there are some settings for tables larger than 2 x 2.
If any of my assumptions are wrong (e.g. the separation of the Parking.locations) I will update my answer.

Comment: you should just copy/paste your code/output rather than post a picture

Comment: that's just the output but I can copy it if it helps.